# How to dissolve IdentityDbContext into MyDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i am new to Entity framework core 1 it's my first time developing a WebApp with .NET core, before that i only worked with traditional asp.net where you could have developed Models using graphic designer, or just generate the models using existing database(i know these things can also be done in .net core but not as simply as it was in .net 4)

i have a complex database model with many one-to-many and many-to-many relations, and it kinda get changed a lot during development and now i am trying the generate a simple db that manages all the models. including both my custom models and ApplicationUser models. and i need to find how to dissolve this default IdentityDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

into:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

i already searched stackoverflow for my answer, some answers suggested different DbContexts for different tables, or creating my website with different databases. i don't find this very good idea. maintaining multiple database is inefficient and considering that almost all my tables are connected with relations having different DbContext is also not very likeable.

and other answers said that all my work can be done in a single DBContext and i remember one answer saying that IdentityDbContext have only 2 extra variables in it (ApplicationUsers and Roles) but none of answers mentioned how to put these 2 elements into MyDbContext. my question in short is how to do that(the question got so long cuz i wanted to make it clear i am not looking for alternative methods)

Comment: you can use more than one dbcontext with single database, I would probably keep the identity context separate and put everything else into one other dbcontext. but if you really want it all in one and don't want to inherit from the IdentityDbContext then you probably need to harvest the code/logic from it for use in your own class. you can find the source code here https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityDbContext.cs

Comment: @JoeAudette more than 1 DbContext can support one Database the reason i choose not to do it is honestly cuz finding tutorials about simple EF core models and contexts was hard enough and i still wasn't able to find any tutorial that cover how to connect different DbContexts
and user tables are connected to a lot of other tables

Comment: @JoeAudette but your comment answered my question anyway, thanks!